# How does CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Mini Dock support two displays from one USB-C port?

Tags: display, usb, dock, displayport

According to the [FAQ](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/questions/product/HMX02ZM/A/caldigit-thunderbolt-3-mini-dock) for the CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 Mini Dock, two different monitors can be connected in extend mode through the single USB-C port. How is this possible if MST is not supported?

Why can one not do the same thing with other USB-C hubs like [this](https://www.hypershop.com/products/hyperdrive-slim-usb-c-hub-for-macbook-ultrabook-chromebook-pc-usb-c-devices?variant=1556434452505) one? It says in their FAQ that one cannot connect two external displays in extend mode on mac because of lack of support of MST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the name: Thunderbolt and USB are two different things, even though they both use the same plug and socket.

USB C offers some of the capabilities - video signal, power transmission, data; but Thunderbolt provides a greater range of data travelling down the same cable.

The Thunderbolt Dock has 2 HDMI ports, which can provide two separate video outputs. The USB hub has one HDMI port.

Comment: Is the problem with the USB-C hub that it is USB-C and not Thunderbolt 3, or is it that it has a mini-display port instead of the second HDMI port, or both? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, it's the nature of USB vs TB. I suspect you can use either video port but not both via USB.